solution-verification | compare to angles in a rectangular parallelipiped
the problem
Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a rectangular parallelepiped with $AB=3a, BC=2a,AA'=6a, a>0$. We denote by $M$ and $N$ the means of $AA'$ and $CC'$ and by $P$ the intersection of the lines $BA'$ and $MB'$. Shown that the measure of the angle formed by DN with C'P is smaller than the measure of the angle formed by DN with the projection of the line C'P on the plane (ABC).
My idea
drawing

MB'ND is a parallelogram because MB'=DN, MD=B'N, so $MB' ||DN => \angle(DN,C'P)=\angle(MB',C'P)=\angle C'PB'$ In triangle C'B'P with one of the angles $90$ we can calculate the $cos \angle C'PB'= \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$
Let $PX\perp AB$=> we can show that $PX\perp (ABCD)$
From the theorem of the nonechidistant parallels we get that $AX=a, XB=2a$
Let $Y\in AB, YA=2a$
Then YXCD is parallelogram and the second the angle we look for is $\angle YDN$
Because $YD=2a\sqrt{2}, DN=3a\sqrt{2}, DN=a\sqrt{38}$ by the thorem of the cosinus the $cos \angle YDN = \frac{11}{24}$
We can show that
$cos \angle YDN< cos \angle C'PB'$ so $\angle YDN> \angle C'PB'$
I'm not sure if the last part of the solution is correct, because I'm not sure that I found the sharp angles and not the obtuse one...also I don't know if the comparative $cos \angle YDN< cos \angle C'PB'$ can surely get us to $\angle YDN> \angle C'PB'$


I have added the drawing. It could be clearer. Otherwise can be deleted.

The word is "midpoint", not "mean"

@jjagmath Oooo...sorry...But still...is my idea corect?

After a quick look at your solution, I think you have at least one error. Your solution says $\cos\angle{YDN}$ is positive. I think this must be wrong since $\angle{YDN}$ must be obtuse.

@mathlove Hey, im still intrested in finding out the solution to this problem. But else should I solve this problem...i thought that it didn't matter if is obtuse or not because $sin(u)=sin(180-u)$.


Because $YD=2a\sqrt{2}, DN=3a\sqrt{2}, DN=a\sqrt{38}$ by the thorem of the cosinus the $cos \angle YDN = \frac{11}{24}$

I think $DN=a\sqrt{38}$ is not correct.
It should be $\color{red}{YN}=a\sqrt{38}$.
I think your calculation is not correct. I got
$$\cos\angle{YDN}=\frac{18a^2+8a^2-38a^2}{2\times 3a\sqrt 2\times 2a\sqrt 2}=\color{red}{-\frac 12}\lt 0$$
which means that $\angle{YDN}$ is obtuse.
Here, I think we can write $\cos\angle(DN,DY)=\color{red}+\dfrac 12\gt 0$.
(I think we can (have to) choose acute angles since we are comparing angles.)
Since $$\cos\angle(DN,C'P)=\sqrt{\frac 23}\gt\frac 12=\cos\angle(DN,DY)$$ we finally get
$$\angle(DN,C'P)\color{red}{\lt}\angle(DN,DY)$$
